# MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json even while Jackson is included

Tags: jax-rs, jersey-2.0, glassfish-4

I've seen some solutions to this problem but it seems like following them doesn't solve my problem.  I am returning a simple string array and when I return it, I am getting this error:

```
Severe:   MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class [Ljava.lang.String;, genericType=class [Ljava.lang.String;.
```

The method is really simple (gets a list of files)

```
   @GET
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public String[] getSegments(@PathParam("userId") String userId,
           @PathParam("deviceId") String deviceId) {
       System.out.println("in get, userId passed: " + userId);
       String[] segments = storage.getSegments(userId, deviceId);  
       return segments;
   }
```

My POM.XML seems to have all the things recommended in other posts:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>RoverServerLib</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet-portability</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-apache-connector</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
       <version>${jersey.version}</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with MOXy. It doesn't know how to handle String arrays. When you have MOXy on the classpath, it is the used as the default. To use Jackson (`jersey-media-json-jackson`). You just need to register the `JacksonFeature`. This will disable MOXy. Note that even just removing MOXy from your project, will have no affect, as Glassfish has it, so you need to make sure to register the `JacksonFeature`.

You should also get rid of `jackson-jaxrs-json-provider`. `jersey-media-json-jackson` already pulls it in (but a different version).

Another thing is that Glassfish already has it's own version of Jersey and friends. If you don't mark all your Jersey related dependencies as `<scope>provided</scope>`, then it's possible you may have version conflicts. So you should make them all `provided`. Glassfish 4.1 uses Jersey 2.10.4. If you need some newer version features, I would recommend [updating Jersey in Glashfish](http://blog.dejavu.sk/2014/01/21/updating-jersey-2-in-glassfish-4/).

Comment: it might be easier for me to get rid of the string array than to monkey with the different configs.  Thanks!

Comment: in the process I found out that my GlassFish release is broken.  Oh joy: https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21440  :) :)